# Get Data attribute from kendo dropdown list in change event

Tags: kendo-dropdown

I set data attribute for kendo dropdown list as below.

> .HtmlAttributes(new {style = "width:100%", required = "required" ,data_id= item.Id})

I tried like this

> $(this).data("id");

but it gives as "undefined". how I get this data attribute value in change event

Answer (score 1):

I Use as below and it works for me

```
this.element.attr('data-id');
```